# Playing dreidel according the Baal Shem Tov

Tags: chanuka, games-toys, baal-shem-tov, dreidel

I saw a video some years back from Lazer Beams (Rabbi Lazer Brody) on how to play dreidel Baal Shem Tov style. I don't remember exactly how to play, and I can't find the video again. One thing in particular that struck out to me that I remember is that gimmel gets you nothing, because in Yiddish gornisht means nothing.

Can anyone help me re-learn this version of dreidel? And yes, it is different than regular dreidel, and yes it does exist.

(By the way, why no tag for dreidel?)

Comment: According to http://seforim.blogspot.com/2005/12/chanukah-customs-and-sources.html, `The earliest Jewish mention of dreidel or the significance of it dates to the late 18th century.` This would probably post-date the Baal Shem Tov. It was however a non-Jewish game for centuries before. I am not sure that he details of a popular non-Jewish game are on topic here, any more than say, a popular set of rules for basketball; a common sport among contemporary Jews.

Comment: @mevaqesh "Some historians date it back about 2000 years and some date it from the early middle ages." Robert Feinerman on the _Chanuka_ dreidel game. He doesn't cite those historians, and may, of course, be wrong.

Comment: @msh210 Indeed it may date to the Roman period; _as a non-Jewish game_ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teetotum.

Comment: Games have no religion as a ball or a dice or a doll, as a pot or a knife and fork.

Comment: @mevaqesh - very interesting link you provided. learned a lot!

Comment: @EzraHoerster My pleasure.

Comment: Found one unconventional way to play dreidel: http://lazerbrody.typepad.com/lazer_beams/2011/12/index.html but not the one i was looking for. scroll down on the webpage